# error in parsing json url in iphone application

Tags: iphone

i am new bie in iPhone application.I want to implement json parsing.I have tried out the samples that are provided on net.But can't find out the exact way how to get index value of url while doing json parsing.has anyone done it earlier.As a beginner can anyone guide me.

Waiting for a positive response

Thanks in advance
Iphone developer

Comment: add the json and the code here

Comment: [what have you tried](http://wwww.whathaveyoutried.com) post your code here

Comment: @alex.. i have followed the following url,tried to impelement .....http://mobiledevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-2.html.....Main problem where i am struck is how to get json array response and get the index value of the first array....waiting for a positive response

Comment: use https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Comment: just enter here your json and code what you have tried and where you have stacked

Answer (score 0):

for your view didload

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:  
                             [NSURL URLWithString:Str_URL]];  
   // NSLog(@"\n\n\n request ===%@\n\n\n",request);
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; 
    if (theConnection) {

        // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.

        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.

        responseData = [[NSMutableData data] init];

    } else {

        // Inform the user that the connection failed.

    }




#pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate methods  
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response { 
    //NSLog(@"\n\n\n response ===%@\n\n\n",response);
    [responseData setLength:0];  
}  

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {  
    //NSLog(@"\n\n\n data ===%@\n\n\n",data);
    [responseData appendData:data];  
}  

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {  
    NSString *strerror = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]];  
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n error ===%@\n\n\n",strerror);

}  

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {  

    //NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if(responseData != nil)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [responseData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
    responseData = nil;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [connection release];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responseData = nil;
    NSLog(@"response String= %@",responseString);

    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil]; 

    NSDictionary *menu = (NSDictionary *) [data objectForKey:@"MainTag"];
    NSString *com=(NSString *) [menu objectForKey:@"yourSubTag"];
}
```